# How do you create a form wizard using Blazor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side

How do you create a form wizard using Blazor + MatBlazor (Material Design for Blazor) and no Javascript?  The user should be able to navigate between different pages of the form and a progress bar should be dynamically updated.

Comment: if you like MatBlazor you might also like Skclusive-UI: https://skclusive.github.io/Skclusive.Material.Docs/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is a basic form wizard that was inspired by [Louis Hendricks](https://itnext.io/building-a-blazor-wizard-with-razor-components-23d652ff06e9).

Please note that you will need to install [MatBlazor](https://www.matblazor.com/) by Vladimir Samoilenko in order to get web elements prefixed by "Mat" working.

**Form.razor File**

```
<div id="form-navigation-container">

    <!-- Checks to see if current step is not equal to first step via SetNavButtons() method -->
    <MatButton Class="previous" disabled="@Wizard.PreviousButtonDisabled" @onclick="Wizard.GoToPreviousStep">Previous Step</MatButton>

    <!-- Checks to see if current step is not equal to last step via SetNavButtons() method -->
    <MatButton Unelevated="true" disabled="@Wizard.NextButtonDisabled" @onclick="Wizard.GoToNextStep">Next Step</MatButton>
</div>

<!-- Progress bar gets incremented/decremented via GoToNextStep()/GoToPreviousStep() methods -->
<MatProgressBar Class="progress" Progress="@Wizard.Progress" aria-valuenow="@Wizard.Progress" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="1"></MatProgressBar>

@code {
    Wizard Wizard = new Wizard();
}
```

**Wizard.cs File**

```
using FORM.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FORM.Models
{
    public class Wizard
    {


        public Wizard()
        {
            Progress = .2;
            Step = 1;
            SetNavButtons();
        }

        public double Progress { get; private set; }

        public int Step { get; private set; }

        public bool PreviousButtonDisabled { get; private set; }
        public bool NextButtonDisabled { get; private set; }

        public void GoToNextStep()
        {
            Step += 1;            
            Progress += .2;
            if (Step == 6)
            {
                Progress = 100;
            }
            SetNavButtons();
        }

        public void GoToPreviousStep()
        {
            if (Step > 1)
            {
                Step -= 1;
                Progress -= .2;
            }
            if (Step == 1)
            {
                Progress = .2;
            }
            SetNavButtons();
        }

        public void SetNavButtons()
        {
            NextButtonDisabled = false;
            switch (Step)
            {
                case 1:
                    PreviousButtonDisabled = true;               
                    break;
                case 2:
                    PreviousButtonDisabled = false;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    PreviousButtonDisabled = false;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    PreviousButtonDisabled = false;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    NextButtonDisabled = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

MudBlazor has been updated more recently and there are some extensions that can be used for the Form Wizard / Stepper

https://mudblazor.com/
https://github.com/CodeBeamOrg/CodeBeam.MudExtensions

```
 <MudStepper @ref="_stepper" ContentStyle="min-height: 400px" Linear="_linear" Vertical="_vertical" Color="_color" Variant="_variant" DisableAnimation="_disableAnimation" HeaderTextView="_headerTextView"
                        PreventStepChange="new Func<bool>(CheckChange)" LocalizedStrings="GetLocalizedStrings()">

                    <MudStep Title="Customer Info" StatusChanged="StatusChanged">
                        <MudForm @ref="_form">
                            <MudStack>
                                <MudTextField T="string" Label="Name" Variant="_variant" Required="true" />
                                <MudTextField T="string" Label="Last Name" Variant="_variant" />
                                <MudTextField T="string" Label="Adress" Variant="_variant" />
                            </MudStack>
                        </MudForm>
                    </MudStep>
                    <MudStep Title="Booking Spec." Optional="true">
                        <MudCheckBox T="bool" Label="Early Check-in" Color="_color" />
                        <MudCheckBox T="bool" Label="Late Check-out" Color="_color" />
                        <MudCheckBox T="bool" Label="Twin Bed" Color="_color" />
                    </MudStep>
                    <MudStep Title="Payment">
                        <MudForm @ref="_form2">
                            <MudStack>
                                <MudTextField T="string" Label="Card Number" Variant="_variant" Required="true" />
                                <MudStack Row="true">
                                    <MudTextField T="string" Label="Expire Date" Variant="_variant" Required="true" />
                                    <MudTextField T="string" Label="CVC" Variant="_variant" Required="true" />
                                </MudStack>
                            </MudStack>
                        </MudForm>
                    </MudStep>
                    
                    @if (_addResultStep)
                    {
                        <MudStep Title="Result Step" IsResultStep="true">
                            <div class="d-flex flex-column align-center justify-center" style="height: 200px">
                                <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Filled.DoneAll" Size="Size.Large" Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Success" />
                                <MudText>Your reservation succesfully completed.</MudText>
                            </div>
                        </MudStep>
                    }
                </MudStepper>
```